# Aerospike: Is there a way to publish stream UDF to the UI?

Tags: aerospike

Building a real time dashboard using aerospike as the database. Aerospike provides a way to create an UDF on a record and then stream it.

I am not able to figure out if this stream could be consumed by UI layer any way. Most probably it is going to be a PHP based UI.

How aerospike's Stream UDF can be consumed by a PHP UI component?

Comment: Okay, there's no PHP UI. Perhaps you mean how do you publish a stream UDF to a PHP application? Also, what do you mean by 'stream'? What are you trying to get back? I want to make sure you need a UDF at all. Can you clarify what exactly you're trying to do with the data?  https://www.aerospike.com/docs/udf/udf_guide.html

Comment: @RonenBotzer That is correct. I am trying to publish a stream UDF to a PHP application. I have a spark streaming job which reads the data from kafka topics and writes the timeseries data to aerospike. From there I want to publish a stream UDF to PHP. It is a time series data coming in to the aerospike that is why I want to publish a UDF.

Comment: Okay, I'm still unclear, so help me understand. On the PHP side you trying to get all the elements between two points in time in a single record? Across multiple records?

Comment: PHP side is real time dashboard. It would be pulling all the values from multiple records. Primary keys are designed in a way to support multiple filter criteria.

Comment: Okay, then you shouldn't be using a stream UDF, because that is a series of functions (like mapreduce) applied to all the records return by a scan or query. Even if you're using a predicate filter, this is a lot of unnecessary IO. So, you should be using the atomic map operations to get all the keys in a time interval. I'll answer below.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To store time-based events that are being continuously appended, you should leverage Aerospike's Map or List data types.

I have posted an example for [using Maps to capture and query events](https://github.com/rbotzer/aerospike-cdt-examples#using-maps-to-capture-and-query-events) (written in Python). The same Map operations exist for the PHP client.

If you store these events in a map with a millisecond timestamp as the key, you can get all the events between two timestamps in PHP using [`Aerospike::operate()`](https://www.aerospike.com/apidocs/php/classes/Aerospike.html#method_operate) method with the operation being `Aerospike::OP_MAP_GET_BY_KEY_RANGE`.

```
$key = $client->initKey("test", "usrhist", 1234);
$operations = [
  ["op" => Aerospike::OP_MAP_GET_BY_KEY_RANGE, "bin" => "events", "key" => 1523474236006, "range_end" => 1523474399000]
];
$options = [];
$status = $client->operate($key, $operations, $returned, $options);
```

To retrieve from multiple keys you'd make this call on each of them in turn.